# Concat LPSTR in C

Tags: c, concatenation

Trying to use as basic C as I can to build a list of numbers from 1-52 in a random order (deck of cards).  Everything works, but all of my attempts to concat the strings and get a result end in failure.  Any suggestions?  NOTE: This is not homework it's something I'm using to create a game.

```
// Locals
    char result[200] = "";  // Result
    int card[52];           // Array of cards
    srand(time(0));         // Initialize seed "randomly"

    // Build
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++) {
        card[i] = i;  // fill the array in order
    }

    // Shuffle cards
    for (int i=0; i<(52-1); i++) {
        int r = i + (rand() % (52-i));
        int temp = card[i]; card[i] = card[r]; card[r] = temp;
    }

    // Build result
    for (int c=0; c<52; c++) {

        // Build
        sprintf(result, "%s%d", result, card[c]);

        // Comma?
        if ( c < 51 )
        {
            sprintf(result, "%s%s", result, ",");
        }
    }
```

My end result is always garbled text.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: How does C or C++ have any effect on "generic as possible" ?

Comment: The most generic way possible in C++ isn't an option in C.  That's how.

Comment: @cHao: What does that even mean? You can write the above code in C or C++, and have both do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Thanatos: Thing is, the above code is C.  If we were talking about C++ (as the question was originally tagged), real strings and/or stringstreams would be much less error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we writing C++ or C? In C++, concat-ing a string is just:

```
string_out = string_a + string_b
```

…since you'd be using `std::string`.

Furthermore, if this is C++, the STL has a `std::shuffle` function.

If this is C, note that all your `sprintf`s aren't concatenating strings, they're just overwriting the old value.

Answer (score 4):

You keep writing to the same position of "result".

`sprintf` is not going to do the appending for you.

You may consider, after each `sprintf`, get the return value (which is the number of char written), and increment the pointer to result buffer. i.e. something like:

(psuedo code):

```
char result[200];
char * outputPtr = result;

for (int c=0; c<52; c++) {

    // Build
    int n = sprintf(outputPtr, "%d%s", card[c], (c<51 ? "," : ""));
    outputPtr += n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would add a comma between each number in the result string:

```
// Get a pointer to the result string
char* ptr = &result[0];
for (int c = 0; c < 52; c++) {

   // Add each cards number and increment the pointer to next position
   ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%d", card[c]);

   // Add a separator between each number
   if (c < 51) {
       *ptr++ = ',';
   }
}
// Make sure the result string is null-terminated
*ptr = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if memory serves, that sprintf will always write into the buffer starting at byte 0. This means that you would be writing the first couple of bytes over and over again with a number, then a comma, then a number. Check if your first bytes are ",[0-9]" - if so, that's your issue.